# How to preserve state of flip card after navigating to another page and then coming back to same page

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, local-storage

I tried to preserve the state of flip card, when I flip card I navigated to another route and after coming back from that page the card again come back to its original state, I want to preserve the flipped card state(back side).here is the code first component that renders is Cards and second one is FlippableCard and third one is Cards.

```
const Cards = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <div className="round-box">Flip a Card</div>

      <div className="flex-container">
        <Remaincard />
        <div className="flex-container-child">
          <div className="flex-child">
            <FlippableCard title={data[0].cardName} key={0} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Cards;
```

```
function Card({ onClick, title }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const timeOutFun = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => navigate("../afterflip/" + title), 300);
    console.log(title);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="card" onClick={onClick}>
        <div className="card-back"></div>

        <div className="card-front">
          <button
            className="middle card-front"
            onClick={() => {
              timeOutFun();
            }}
          >
            hiii
          </button>
          <p
            onClick={() => {
              timeOutFun();
            }}
            className="text-on-card"
          >
            {title}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
function FlippableCard({ title, key }) {
  
  const [showFront, setShowFront] = useState(true);
  // console.log("showFront");
  const [color, setColor] = useState("#110781");

  return (
    <div className="scroll-remove">
      <div className="flippable-card-container">
        <CSSTransition in={showFront} timeout={300} classNames="flip">
          <Card
            title={title}
            value={key}
            onClick={() => {
              setShowFront((v) => !v);
              setColor("#A8A8A8");
              setShowFront(false);
              // getLocalData();
            }}
          />
        </CSSTransition>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it just the one `FlippableCard` component? Or are you rendering an array of card data to "flippable" cards? What have you tried? Can you [edit] to include clearer details for what you are trying to do and what or where you have an issue? See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using [localStorage.setItem](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_setitem.asp) and [localStorage.getItem](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_storage_getitem.asp). This will store the data in the browser indefinitely using cache. If you want the data to be deleted or in other words, refreshed, you can use session storage. This retains data until that particular tab is closed.